# download directory and sub directories off a virtual repository

Tags: recursion, download, directory, repository

Wondering if there is a way to download the root folder plus a bunch of sub folders (and sub folders of those folders) with all the files and keep them in their respective folders.

I've tried some firefox plugins like flashgot and download-them-all but they grab the actual web files in addition to the files in the repository, but only if they are visible. For example, if I don't collapse all the folders and expose the files in the repository, the plugins won't detect them.

I would just collapse all the folders and expose the files but these plugins won't recognize the folders...they just download as "foldername".html  .... and all the files are mixed together in one folder.

I've also tried visualWget and allowed recursive downloads but again, this only grabs the actual website files, not the files in the repository.

If anyone could help it'd  be greatly appreciated. I've been copying them manually but there are literally thousands of files and folders so I'm looking for a quicker solution.

Comment: **forgot to add that I don't have access to the site's server. Only as a user...(e.g. dropbox, googledrive). It's actually a repository on a university website so no advanced features like dropbox or googledrive. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work. I used the following command in Terminal.

scp -r username@hostaddress:/file/path/to/directory /path/to/my/computer/directory

-r is for recursive so it downloads all files and directories and subdirectors

If you try this be sure to run this command from your local terminal. I made the mistake of doing it from the SSH connection to the server (no negative effects just frustrating)

Comment: What about downloading a **specific file type** using **VisualWget**? Is it possible to download only **mp3** files in a directory and its sub-directories in **VisualWget**?

Answer (score 0):

As a client you can only download what's accessible.  You either need to know the list of files or crawl the pages for the links, which is what the Firefox plugins do.

There's no way to get a list of files on the server without access to the server beyond http (unless the server has webdav or exposes some other api).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have access to all the files except I need to open each folder then download the contents manually. I've been able to speed this up a little with the plugins but unfortunately they don't download the folders properly.

Comment: What about downloading a **specific file type** using **VisualWget**? Is it possible to download only **mp3** files in a directory and its sub-directories in **VisualWget**?